# implementation of shell elements in a topology optimization algorithm

Tags: finite-element, optimization, solid-mechanics

I am working on developing a topology optimization solver based on the finite element method and I want to add a triangular shell element in it. I used the classic finite element method but I didn’t separate in-plane and off-plane strains. My strain-displacement matrix consists of the following:

$$
B_i=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial x} & 0 & 0 & 0 & z\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial x} & 0\\
0 & \frac{\partial N_i}{\partial y} & 0 & -z\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial y} & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial N_i}{\partial x} & 0 & -z\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial x} & z\frac{\partial N_i}{\partial y} & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{\partial N_i}{\partial y} & 0 & \kappa N_i & 0\\
0 & 0 & \frac{\partial N_i}{\partial x} & -\kappa N_i & 0 & 0\\
\end{array}\right)
$$

And the shape function is:

$$
N(\xi,\eta)=\begin{cases}
N_1=1-\xi-\eta\\
N_2=\xi\\
N_3=\eta
\end{cases}
$$

I tried to validate my implementation with an example a cantilever beam: fixed on the left side and a concentrated force applied in the lower right corner and here is my Von Mises stresses distribution:

[image]

And my topology optimization is (optimal criteria used):

[image]

The results I obtain from Abaqus with the same properties, for Von Mises stresses distribution are depicted as follows:

[image]

The results that I get from my code are different from the results of Abaqus and I am not sure why. But here are their solutions and modifications I tried without any tangible difference in the obtained results:

- I used a transformation matrix otherwise the calculation doesn’t run
- The transformation matrix applied only in the calculation of the stiffness matrix (its dimension is $18\times 18$)
- I tried to formulate the shape function in $(x,y)$ basis instead of $(\xi,\eta)$ but there was no difference

What do you think might be the source of error in my implementation? If you need more information about the way I implemented my code please tell me to clarify.

Comment: I would suggest that you *verificate* your implementation against an analytical solution. What about a spherical vessel?

Comment: Since your example is a cantilever beam with in-plane DOFs only, I suggest testing your implementation by fixing all the out of plane DOFs. It will be easy to debug your code this way.